# How do I carry over the final player score to be used as the starting score for the next round?

Tags: python, function, loops, scoring

In my programming class we are creating a dice poker game. Once a round is complete and the player receives their score, that score is supposed to be used as the new starting point for the next round. In the code you can see me trying to make "newPlayPoints" become "playingPoint", however I am unsure if that is the correct way to go about this. I'm sure the coding is a little messy due to my beginner status, but the main sections to look at would be under the function "updatePlayPoints" and the comment that reads "#Attempting to get playingPoint to become new "newPlayPoints". Thank you for the help!

```
from random import randint

def rollFiveDie():

    allDie = []
    for x in range(5):
        allDie.append(randint(1,6))

    return allDie

def outputUpdate(P, F):

    print(P)
    print(F)

def rollSelect():

    rollSelected = input("Which die would you like to re-roll? (Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 from the list)   ")
    print("  ")
    selectList = rollSelected.split()

    return selectList

def rollPicked(toRollList, diceList):

    for i in toRollList:
        diceList[int(i) - 1] = randint(1,6)

def scoring(dList):

    counts = [0] * 7
    for value in dList:
        counts[value] = counts[value] + 1

    if 5 in counts:
        score = "Five of a Kind", 30
    elif 4 in counts:
        score = "Four of a Kind", 25
    elif (3 in counts) and (2 in counts):
        score = "Full House", 15
    elif 3 in counts:
        score = "Three of a Kind", 10
    elif not (2 in counts) and (counts[1] == 0 or counts[6] == 0):
        score = "Straight", 20
    elif counts.count(2) == 2:
        score = "Two Pair", 5
    else:
        score = "Lose", 0

    return score

def numScore(diList):

    counts = [0] * 7
    for v in diList:
        counts[v] = counts[v] + 1

    if 5 in counts:
        finScore = 30
    elif 4 in counts:
        finScore = 25
    elif (3 in counts) and (2 in counts):
        finScore = 15
    elif 3 in counts:
        finScore = 10
    elif not (2 in counts) and (counts[1] == 0 or counts[6] == 0):
        finScore = 20
    elif counts.count(2) == 2:
        finScore = 5
    else:
        finScore = 0

    return finScore

def printScore(fscore):
    print(fscore)
    print("  ")

def trackScore(score1, score2):

    comScore = (score1) + (score2)

    return comScore

#Starting Points
playPoints = 100
print("New round! Your points are: ", playPoints)
newPlayPoints = 100 - 10


def updatePlayPoints(nPP, PP):

    nPP = PP

    return nPP


def diceGame():

    contPlaying = True
    while contPlaying:


        playing = input("It takes 10 points to play. Would you like to play the Dice Game? (Answer 'y' or 'n'):  ")
        print('  ')

        if playing == 'y':

            #First Roll
            fiveDie = rollFiveDie()

            outputUpdate("Your roll is...", fiveDie)

            #Choosing Second Roll/Second Roll execution
            pickDie = input("Which die would you like to re-roll? (Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 from the list)   ")
            print("   ")
            pickDie = pickDie.split()

            rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

            outputUpdate("Your next roll is...", fiveDie)

            #Choosing Last Roll
            pickDie = rollSelect()

            rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

            outputUpdate("Your final roll is...", fiveDie)

            #Scoring output

            finalScore = numScore(fiveDie)

            print(scoring(fiveDie))

            fiveDieScore = numScore(fiveDie)

            finalPoints = newPlayPoints + finalScore

            print(finalPoints)

            #Attempting to get playingPoint to become new "newPlayPoints"
            playingPoint = trackScore(fiveDieScore, newPlayPoints)

            if playingPoint > 10:
                playingPoint - 10

            else:
                    print("No more points to spend. Game Over.")
                    contPlaying = False

            updatePlayPoints(newPlayPoints, playingPoint)

        else:

            contPlaying = False

def main():

    diceGame()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `newPlayPoints` but you aren't setting them to anything. You are just calling `updatePlayPoints` and doing nothing with the return value. You don't need `trackscore`, `updatePlayPoints` or `newPlayPoints`. Instead add `fiveDieScore` to `PlayingPoint`. Also, the way it is set up now the player can start the game with no points. I am assuming that there should be an initial number of points the person starts with, I set it to 10. So now every turn you check if the player has enough points to even play and if they do immediately subtract out those points. Think about it as if it were an arcade game. You have to have a quarter to play and the first thing you do is pay to play. The way you subtract out the points does nothing. `PlayingPoint - 10` is a valid line but you set it to nothing so it does nothing.

```
def diceGame():

contPlaying = True
PlayingPoints = 10 #Initial points
while contPlaying:


    playing = input("It takes 10 points to play. Would you like to play the Dice Game? (Answer 'y' or 'n'):  ")
    print('  ')

    if playing == 'y' and PlayingPoint >= 10:

        #Subtract the points used for the turn
        PlayingPoint -= 10

        #First Roll
        fiveDie = rollFiveDie()

        outputUpdate("Your roll is...", fiveDie)

        #Choosing Second Roll/Second Roll execution
        pickDie = input("Which die would you like to re-roll? (Choose 1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5 from the list)   ")
        print("   ")
        pickDie = pickDie.split()

        rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

        outputUpdate("Your next roll is...", fiveDie)

        #Choosing Last Roll
        pickDie = rollSelect()

        rollPicked(pickDie, fiveDie)

        outputUpdate("Your final roll is...", fiveDie)

        #Scoring output

        finalScore = numScore(fiveDie)
        print(scoring(fiveDie))

        fiveDieScore = numScore(fiveDie)

        finalPoints = PlayingPoint + finalScore
        print(finalPoints)

        playingPoint += fiveDieScore            

    else:

        contPlaying = False
```

To sum up the changes I removed `TrackScore`, `UpdatePlayPoints`, and `newPlayPoints`. Added the point check to the beginning rather than the end